# Var (X) = 0 if and only if X is degenerate.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was able to prove one way.

i.e. X is degenerate if for some a $\epsilon$  $\mathbb{R}$ P{X = a} = 1.

=> EX = a. P{X=a} = a

EX<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup>

=> Var (X) = 0

But the other way around is not clear.

Var (X) = 0 => EX = EX<sup>2</sup>

I am stuck here. Not able to prove that X is degenerate. Could someone help.
Also, if my other proof is correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

We actually have $(\mathbb EX)\color{red}{^2}=\mathbb E(X^2)$. Use the following facts:

1. If $Y$ is a non-negative random variable such that $\mathbb E(Y)=0$, then $\mathbb P(Y=0)=1$.
2. Use this with $Y=(X-\mathbb E(X))^2$.

Comment: Sorry if this is lame, I don't get how if E(Y) = 0, then P(Y = 0) = 1. Also, it only proves Y is a degenerate RV. But I need to prove X is degenerate. Thanks.

Comment: @user2761431: $\{Y=0\}=\{X={\rm E}[X]\}$.